# How to display long text in android without using strings.xml?

Tags: android

Because using string.xml is gonna take up a lot of space for very long text.

Taking List of Abbreviations shown below for example.Is it better using strings.xml or any other method ?

```
a(in dates)     ante
abbrev.     abbreviation (of)
Abbrev.     abbreviation(s)
Abd.        Aberdeen
Aberd.      Aberdeen
abl.        ablative
Abol.       abolition
Aborig.     aboriginal
Abp.        archbishop
Abr.        abridged
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything is the res folder is compressed in the APK.  Use the strings.xml folder.  ASCII text compress nicely in the APK.